# Clearing page after calling external method in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have to use widget provided by simplybook but when i call method to get widget iframe whole page is reloading and automaticly override whole page for some reason. Is there any solution to call method and prevent react to automaticly return it?

`<script src="//simplybook.it/v2/widget/widget.js"></script>`

`<script>var widget = new SimplybookWidget()</script>`

I want it to appear in modal but wherever i place method call it replace everything

I tried to render that before and after body the result is the same, even if i call it in console it will force page to override